# Просмотренные и непросмотренные объекты Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

У меня есть модель "Форма". Формы отправляют пользователи на сайте. Таких объектов в панели администрирования со временем собирается достаточно много, поэтому было бы удобно визуально отличать просмотренные формы и непросмотренные. Соответственно, непрочитанные должны в панели администрирования отображаться, к примеру, красным. Прочитанные - зеленым. Как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Нужен код представления Ваших форм в админку.  И модели. Минимум...

Answer (score 1):

Прочитанные формы должны содержать некий флажок, модельное свойство. В зависимости от него виджет формы должен принимать атрибут class. В классе и будет прописано, зеленая форма или красная.

Comment: А что, так можно было ответить? Некий класс, некая функция...

Comment: Каков вопрос - таков и ответ. Так я подумал